# Binutils fails to build when building GCC Cross Compiler

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, osdev, binutils

I am building a GCC 6.10 cross-compiler. I am using the [tutorial](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) from OSDev. When I go and build binutils using my shell sript, I get an error like this: [image: Binutils error as mentioned]

I used a shell script to move ClooG and ISL into the `build-binutils` directory as specified in the tutorial I mentioned above. Here is my shell script:

```
export PREFIX="$HOME/opt/cross"
export TARGET=i686-elf
export PATH="$PREFIX/bin:$PATH"

cd $HOME/src

mv isl-0.17 binutils-2.9.1/isl
mv cloog-0.18.4 binutils-2.9.1/cloog

mkdir build-binutils
cd build-binutils
../binutils-2.9.1/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --with-sysroot --disable-nls --disable-werror
make
make install
```

I am using the latest versions from their websites. GCC, as mentioned in the tutorial above, installs fine but binutils doesn't. Binutils starts to setup but it eventually crashes. Is this a bug within binutils itself or have I done something wrong with the setup? Am I using the incorrect versions? Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of _GCC_ are you trying to build?

Comment: I am trying to build GCC 6.1.0. I download the zip file from the GNU website. I am using the website I mentioned in the question to build it with the other packages.

Comment: Binutils 2.9.1 is actually a version from almost 20 years. 2.9.1 is less than 2.26. If you are building a 6.10 GCC cross compiler you will want to use binutils-2.26. This is based upon this chart of known [successful builds](http://wiki.osdev.org/Cross-Compiler_Successful_Builds)

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't notice that. I will try to rebuild binutils with version 2.26.

Comment: @Michael Petch Thankyou very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to see people take the advice of building a *GCC* cross-compiler to avoid potential problems with host environment *GCC* compilers and their native header files.

Versioning of *BINUTILS* (and many projects) use versioning of major.minor.patch. A value of 9 < 26, 1 < 2 etc. Binutils-2.9.1 is from the late 1990's. The latest is version 2.26. In this case 9 < 26 so the 2.9.x releases are earlier than 2.26.x. With this in mind, one should consult the [successful build matrix](http://wiki.osdev.org/Cross-Compiler_Successful_Builds) on the OSDEV Wiki.

You are building a *GCC* 6.10 cross compiler. Member(s) on OSDev (as of this writing) have found that [Binutils-2.26](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/) has successfully been used to build GCC 6.10 cross compilers.